# pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth() behavior in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pd.offsets, weekofmonth

With `pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.WeekOfMonth.html):

- `2020-08-10` (i.e. `Monday`) offsets to `2020-08-12` as expected i.e. `Wednesday` of 2nd week (i.e. `week=1`)

Trying to understand why doesn't:

- `2020-08-01` offset to `2020-08-05` instead of `2020-08-12`.
- `2020-08-21` offset to `2020-08-26` instead of `2020-09-09`.

`[Python 3.9.13; pandas: 2.0.1]`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd     
data = pd.Series(
     [pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 01:01:01.001001001'), # Saturday
     pd.Timestamp('2020-08-10 01:01:01.001001001'),  # Monday
     pd.Timestamp('2020-08-21 01:01:01.001001001')]) # Friday
print(data)
print()
```

Offset:

```
w = data + pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)
print(w)
```

Output:

```
0   2020-08-01 01:01:01.001001001 # Saturday
1   2020-08-10 01:01:01.001001001 # Monday
2   2020-08-21 01:01:01.001001001 # Friday
dtype: datetime64[ns]

0   2020-08-12 01:01:01.001001001 # Wednesday
1   2020-08-12 01:01:01.001001001 # Wednesday
2   2020-09-09 01:01:01.001001001 # Wednesday
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use a positive Offset, this will give you the **next** "second Wednesday of the month".

If you're before one "second Wednesday of a month", this will remain in the same month, otherwise go to the next month's "second Wednesday".

```
pd.Timestamp('2020-08-11') + pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)
# Timestamp('2020-08-12 00:00:00')

pd.Timestamp('2020-08-12') + pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)
# Timestamp('2020-09-09 00:00:00')
```

Likewise, using a negative offset:

```
pd.Timestamp('2020-08-12') - pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)
# Timestamp('2020-07-08 00:00:00')

pd.Timestamp('2020-08-13') - pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)
# Timestamp('2020-08-12 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code `data + pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)` is used to add an offset to a given date. This offset allows us to shift dates and times forwards or backward in a flexible manner.

The parameters used in `pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=1, weekday=2)` have specific meanings:

- `week=1` represents the 2nd week of a month, where the weeks are numbered starting from `0` for the first week.
- `weekday=2` represents the third day of the week, which corresponds to `Monday` (since weekdays are numbered starting from `0`).
  Here's what the code does step by step:

When we apply the offset to a given date, it calculates the date of the third weekday of the second week of the same month as the provided date.

**For a positive offset:**

If the provided date (`2020-08-01`) comes before the calculated date (`2020-08-12`) using the `week` and `weekday`, it returns the calculated date. For example, if the input date is `2020-08-01`, the calculated date is `2020-08-12`.
While if the provided date (`2020-08-21`) comes after the calculated date (`2020-09-09`) using the `week` and `weekday`, it returns the date of the same weekday in the second week of the next month. For example, if the input date is `2020-08-21`, the calculated date is `2020-08-12`, but since the input date is after this calculated date, it moves to the next month and calculates the date again. The result is `2020-09-09`.

**For a negative offset**

It will work oppositely in this case. Let's say the provided date (`2020-08-01`) comes before the calculated date (`2020-08-12`) then, it will return the second Wednesday of the previous month.